# How to bind a v-model with a method in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am learning vuejs (3).

I have this loop:

```
<tr v-for="index in 7" :key="index">
            <td>
              {{ index }} {{ getDayOfTheWeek ? getDayOfTheWeek(index) : null }}
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="time" class="form-control" id="time_slot1_start" v-model="getTimeSlot1Start(index)" />
            </td>
```

And the function *getTimeSlot1Start* is declared like that:

```
methods: {

getTimeSlot1Start (day) {
      return this.openingHours.find(i => i.day === day).time_slot1_start
    },
```

When I want to save my file, eslint tells me:

> error  'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS  vue/valid-v-model

Why do I get message? Is it not possible to bind a model with a function?

Comment: What's supposed to happen when the user types in the input? What do you want to set? If you do want to set something, you should use a [computed with getter and setter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-model` directive is two-way binding which accepts a property as value not a method, you could bind that method using `value` attribute `@input` event to edit the item specified by the index :

```
<input ...  :value="getTimeSlot1Start(index)" @input="setTimeSlot1Start(index)" />
```